# How to change the marker for the overlay on tap for android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

i have made an application in which i need to change the drawable of an overlayitem when a user clicks on it. i am using the following code to achieve this effect:

```
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        if(item.getTitle().equals("true")){
            if(item.getMarker(OverlayItem.ITEM_STATE_FOCUSED_MASK).equals(greenMarker)){
                item.setMarker(orangeMarker);
                view1ComplainPoleList.add(item.getSnippet());
                Log.i("adding",item.getSnippet());
                map.invalidate();
            }
            else{
                item.setMarker(greenMarker);
                view1ComplainPoleList.remove(item.getSnippet());
                Log.i("removing",item.getSnippet());
                map.invalidate();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But this does not seem to be working. whenever i click on an overlayitem it disappears from view. what is going wrong?

UPDATE:

could you also tell me how to load new views when the map is scrolled...?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in your code?  It would be a lot simpler to do this in xml.  Android provides a way to define state drawables (focused, pressed, default) with xml.

Comment: could you please elaborate a better way to do this if you know.

Comment: Could it be the case where you have not set the marker drawable bounds?

Comment: @user7777.. could you please elaborate what you are saying?

Comment: Like `mOverlaydrawable.setBounds(imgRect);` required if you manually drawing the overlay.

Comment: So to whom will you award the bounty? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is ***very simple to do***:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    //Get the new Drawable
    Drawable marker = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    //Set its bounds
    marker.setBounds(0,0,marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
    //Set the new marker
    item.setMarker(marker);
    //Return true! Do not invalidate
    return true;
}
```

Comment: don't i need to invalidate the mapview?

Comment: Use this code! The main this you forgot is the 'setbounds' statement

Comment: so map.invalidate is not required?

Comment: It seems you still did not try my code? I tried it and it is working great. Just do not forget the `setbounds` statement

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of answers here doing this the hard way. If you have 2 images and you want to flip them based on focus, do it the easy way:

Step 1: Copy both images into a drawables folder:

Example: mycon_focused.png, mycon.png

Step 2: Create a selector xml file in drawables: Example "marker.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mycon_focused"/>
     <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/mycon" />
</selector>
```

Step 3: When you create your ItemOverlay and add the OverlayItems drawable, use

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
```

instead of

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mycon);
```

and then programically changing it in the on tap method. After reading through many answers and not seeing this anywhere I just tried it myself, and it worked perfectly.

Much thanks to previous contributors, without your help I wouldn't have had a starting point.

Another note: If you're using Sherif elKhatib suggested code and your marker position is off try:

```
int width = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
marker.setBounds(-(width/2),-height,(width/2),0);
```

instead of

```
marker.setBounds(0,0,marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

This should center it perfectly.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey thanks for the edit. Next time try a comment first. I don't often see people directly editing post (no one else on this post for example) so I'm not certain of the etiquette.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what `view1ComplainPoleList` is and whether it is impacting matters. I handled this by subclassing `OverlayItem` and overriding `getMarker()` to return the proper image. [Here is the sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk) in which I use this technique.

Comment: view1complaipolelist is an array which groups the markers that are selected.

Comment: i saw the code that you gave me a link to. i made a cutom overlayitem class but still upon clicking the image of the overlay is not changing.

Comment: @user590849: Download and run my sample project. If the sample project does not work unmodified, let me know what environment you are testing it in. If the sample project does work, find out what you are doing differently and fix it.

Comment: ok, the code is running. but i don't understand that after the ontap event is called how does your overlay drawable change? what part of the code is doing the change?

Comment: @user590849 You need to press the 'H' key when you have focus to toggle the marker

Comment: @user590849: In my example, `onTap()` does not control the icon change. Pressing the H key does. I override `onKeyDown()` in the activity and call `toggleHeart()` on the overlay from there. The overlay finds the focused item, has it update what image it will use, then invalidates the `MapView`. In principle, you should be able to call `toggleHeart()` from the indexed `onTap()` method in the overlay -- I was using that event for other purposes.

Comment: i tried doing what you had done in your project but it is not doing anything. i am not able to change the images.

Answer (score 2):

Use Setbounds api to set the bounds as follows: Edited your original code

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    if(item.getTitle().equals("true")){
        if(item.getMarker(OverlayItem.ITEM_STATE_FOCUSED_MASK).equals(greenMarker)){
            orangeMarker.setBounds(0,0,orangeMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(),orangeMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());
            item.setMarker(orangeMarker);
            view1ComplainPoleList.add(item.getSnippet());
            Log.i("adding",item.getSnippet());
            map.invalidate();
        }
        else{
            greenMarker.setBounds(0,0,greenMarker.getIntrinsicWidth(),greenMarker.getIntrinsicHeight());
            item.setMarker(greenMarker);
            view1ComplainPoleList.remove(item.getSnippet());
            Log.i("removing",item.getSnippet());
            map.invalidate();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```