# Understanding code to change the marker for the overlay on tap in Android

Tags: java, android, android-maps

I tried an [answer by Sherif elKhatib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177125/387076) to [How to change the marker for the overlay on tap for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038636/how-to-change-the-marker-for-the-overlay-on-tap-for-android), but there are things I don't understand.

```
protected boolean onTap(int index)
{
    // Here, what is mOverlays? I mean it is the object of what?
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    // Is the mContext, the object of Context?
    Drawable marker = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    marker.setBounds(0,0,marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
    item.setMarker(marker);
    return true;
}
```

What are `mOverlays` and `mContext`?

Answer (score 1):

> What are mOverlays and mContext?

`mOverlays` presumably is a `List<OverlayItem>`, since it responds to `get()` with an `OverlayItem`.

`mContext` is a `Context`, probably your `MapActivity`.